# Static object being set on second call to Web API

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, static

I am working with a Asp.Net Core Web API and I'm having an issue with one of my static object properties only being set on the second call to the controller.

I have some code that executes before the controller action via a attribute `[ValidateAuthToken]` that I created. The code for that looks something like this

```
public async override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //If our token is valid, no need to do anything.
            if (!TokenStorage.AuthToken.IsTokenExpired())
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }else{
              TokenStorage.AuthToken.Token = service.GetToken();
         }
```

On my controller I have something like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Contents([FromBody] Model request)
{
   var result = service.GetPageData(request.PageName, TokenStorage.AuthToken.TokenType, TokenStorage.AuthToken.Token);

    return Ok();
}
```

`AuthToken` is a static object on the `TokenStorage` class.

From debugging it seems like `null` values are being passed into the service call in the controller, the first time around. The second time around it seems like those values are there. I checked that the values are getting generated on and set to the static object before it hits the controller.

From doing some reading it seems like this is a threading issue, but I'm not knowledgeable enough on threading or threading in the ASP.NET Core environment to come up with a solution and Google has turned up results that don't really fit in my situation.

Any insight would be great.

Comment: What does the service GetToken call do? Is that an asynchronous operation that perhaps is retrieving the token on the first call (not finished) and because you are not awaiting then it is ready on the second call?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidelines on posting code. Based on your explanation (which does not completely align with code shown as it is unclear where `ValidateAuthToken` is used) there can't be any threading issues as you expect filter to run on the same active thread as actual controller action... But why it does not happen is impossible to say whiteout actual example. (Obviously you should protect access to static fields in multithreaded case like this but it does not matter for this *example* itself)

Comment: @Carlos - ah yes, silly of me to forgot to mention that. GetToken from the service is in fact an async HttpClient call. That’s probably what’s doing it. 

How do you recommend I go about syncing these calls and/or making sure my first service call is finished before it hits the controller action? It is worth mentioning that my GetPageData call is also eventually going to be an async call.

Comment: If that’s an async function then that should be awaited. But I would wonder why you need a token service in the backend if that’s an API. Surely the client should be sending the token through? That’s to me the way of proceeding. Is that something you cannot implement? Typically a JWT token can be in the headers and ASPNET Authorization attribute would handle it. In fact the controller action wouldn’t get executed if the token is invalid. Perhaps that’s what you should look at? I’m talking without knowing the actual system and the architecture of your solution

Comment: @Carlos - Not getting into it too much, the token is unable to be held on the clients side for various reasons in the architecture. Back to the issue, I am awaiting my call to get the token, but because I’m waiting it it’s hitting my controller action next. So it’s like Pre Controller (Await) -> Controller service call (null values) -> Pre Controller await finished. How would I go about awaiting the call from the Pre-Controller method before executing the main controller service call?

Comment: I'm not sure how can you work around it. I suppose that you would have to fetch the token in your controller method...it just does not feel right the fact you fetch the token in the middleware